How to install OpenCL on Expo for Android?
I am following the instructions to try and install a GPUDelegate on my android device.  The docs for the library say to:

To enable GPU or NNAPI delegate in Android, you may need to include OpenCL library with uses-native-library on application scope in AndroidManifest.xml, starting from Android 12.

> <!-- Like this -->
> <uses-native-library android:name="libOpenCL.so" android:required="false" />
> 
> <!-- You may need one/all of the followings depends on your targeting devices -->
> <uses-native-library android:name="libOpenCL-pixel.so" android:required="false" />
> <uses-native-library android:name="libGLES_mali.so" android:required="false" />
> <uses-native-library android:name="libPVROCL.so" android:required="false" />

Using Expo/React Native, my question is 1) how do I install the uses-native-libary and 2) add OpenCL?
